# multiplayer game server

Tags: erlang, backend, multiplayer

I want to write a server-side app to manage multiplayer game communications (probably for multiple simple games, mostly turn-based). It should be robust and highly scalable.

I want to know a bit more about the technology posibilities I have. Does anyone have any experience with Erlang? Does it cost more development time to create a server than with other languages? is it much faster, or has better scalability than others?

What language would you say would be best?

Comment: See, for example, "[How/why do functional languages (specifically Erlang) scale well?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/474497/298282)".

Comment: Yes. No, but that assumes you aren't also learning the language at the same time. It's fast and scalable enough, but only if you know what you're doing. Erlang is certainly one of the best for this kind of application, but it's a terrible language for people who can't be bothered to learn it properly.

Comment: I am with YOUR ARGUMENT IS VALID here. It is hard to make a program perform well, but very easy to make it perform badly. If you come with the right kind of ideas and know Erlang, it is a very good solution language. If you don't have the necessary amount of knowledge however, you will only be shooting yourself in your foot. So tl;dr: Yes, Erlang is an excellent choice for this kind of problem in general.

Comment: Can give some anecdotal answer here: I chose Erlang for a real production project three years ago and I learnt it while going along.  In hindsight this was a great choice, and I wasn't slower implementing than if I would have used C or a similar nonfunctional language.  And with my application was a unconventional choice, but this made the difference in the product today because actually erlang was suited very well. Disclaimer: I learn programming languages fast and know > 20 of them, and had done some programs in Lisp for fun before. So YMMV.

Comment: To add to this: I also implemented a multiplayer game server in Erlang as a toy project last year (for card games) and Erlang is a perfect fit.  So my opinion: just do it and use it as an excuse for learning a great language ... but please learn it well and don't complain ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what problem you are trying to solve, there isn't a good way to answer your question.  However, Erlang does generally scale well, assuming you both code it well and architect it well.  If you are considering implementing your backend as a RESTful service, I'd question any decision to use Erlang -- maybe it's still a good fit, but I'd ask you why.  However, if you decided to base the backend of your game on XMPP, I'd suggest that erlang and ejabberd is a superb fit.  It all depends on how you are writing the software.

Also, does it cost more in development time compared to other languages?  Quite possibly.  As a python expert and an Erlang learner, I can write python code in 10 minutes which will take me 2 hours to do in Erlang.  But I'd bet that Joe Armstrong (Erlang inventor) could write Erlang code pretty darn quickly.

In short, your question cannot be answered accurately.  I've attempted to provide some information which may help you understand why.